# Nimbuzz is encrypted?

Tags: xmpp, nimbuzz

I'm capturing nimbuzz traffic on ipad galaxy and pc and it seems sometimes the traffic in the xmpp is some binary? is it encrypted? does anyone know how to read it ? it is not in plain text.. example to a packet text : is it compressed perhaps? does anyone know how to decompress it?

```
\262\311,\004\371E\311\320\300\330$>\263 #?/53%^I\241\244\262 \325V\t\250\2424\247D\211D\327\331\331de\246\330\025\344\224\002\2238(\225\033: \205\213>\304\022SKc#`v\002)\264\321\a\351\002R\231\205v\000\000\000\000\377\377
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be both compressed and encrypted.  Please start by reading [RFC 6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120), then perhaps [XEP-0138](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0138.html).